# Parsing float followed by string containing "e" character

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I'm trying to parse this type of string

```
1.2e3ex
1.2e3 ex
```

And have set up

```
x3::float_ >> "ex"
```

Unfortunately, this fails to parse

```
1ex
```

Full example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

const auto parser = x3::float_ >> "em";

int main()
{
  std::string input = "1em";
  auto first = input.begin();
  auto last = input.end();

  float value{};
  bool result = x3::phrase_parse(first, last, parser, x3::blank, value);

  if(result)
  {
    if(first == last)
      std::cout << "parse succesful: " << value << '\n';
    else
      std::cout << "incomplete parse: " << value << '\n';
  }
  else
    std::cout << "parse unsuccesful\n";
}
```

Available [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5466c1f36124ef4a) as well.

It seems I'd need to jump through some hoops,

```
struct non_scientific_float_policy : x3::real_policies<float>
{
  template <typename Iterator>
  static bool parse_exp(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last)
  {
    return false;
  }
};

const auto non_scientific_float = x3::real_parser<float, non_scientific_float_policy>{};
```

and [provide an alternative](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7deae11e87f2a9f):

```
const auto parser = non_scientific_float >> "em" | x3::float_ >> "em";
```

Is there no other way?

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve] for what the problem is?

Comment: @Nicol the first coliru link is exactly that. The 'e' in "em" is greedily taken by the `float_` parser, and never given back.

Comment: "*the first coliru link is exactly that.*" MCVE go *into* your post, not in links.

Comment: Apparently, when it's not a new user, the whole "be welcoming" dance goes right out the window ;)

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm just going to be blunt: there is no "rule"/suggestion/whatever I can find that specifies MCVE's should go _in_ the question body, so please don't start making up rules for the sake of argument. Having it in an editable, runnable form is a bonus you get for free...

Comment: @rubenvb: [Yes, there is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334461/734069) [such a rule.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269253/734069)

Comment: @NicolBolas Two posts on meta a rule does not make. At least link to the bit in the help center I overlooked: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." Anyhoo, all the glorious code is now available for your viewing pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the issue by tuning the real policy `parse_exp` in such way that exponent detection must expect not only `[eE]` character but `[eE][-+]?[0-9]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

template <typename T>
struct alt_real_policies : x3::real_policies<T>
{
    template <typename Iterator>
    static bool parse_exp(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last)
    {
        Iterator save = first;
        if (x3::real_policies<T>::parse_exp(first, last)) {
            Iterator iter = first;
            if (x3::extract_int<x3::unused_type, 10, 1, 1>::call(iter, last, x3::unused))
                return true;
        }
        first = save;
        return false;
    }

};

const x3::real_parser<float, alt_real_policies<float>> altfloat;
const auto parser = altfloat >> "em";

int main()
{
    std::string input = "1em";
    auto first = input.begin();
    auto last = input.end();

    float value{};
    bool result = x3::phrase_parse(first, last, parser, x3::blank, value);

    if (result)
    {
        if (first == last)
            std::cout << "parse succesful: " << value << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "incomplete parse: " << value << '\n';
    }
    else
        std::cout << "parse unsuccesful\n";
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f60f334c960cb602

Comment: I like it. Would be even better if instead of `extract_int` it would reuse `parse_exp_n` (quoting from memory), I feel

Comment: That was also my idea, but `parse_exp_n` needs a real value; it also will parse all digits and return false if the number overflows int - this will lead to incorrectly ignored exponent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative policy for non-greedy parsing of the exponent. The very simplest I can think of is:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d411407cf3dbe1d9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

template <typename T>
struct no_exponent : x3::real_policies<T> {
    template <typename It>
        static bool parse_exp(It, It) { return false; }
};

x3::real_parser<double, no_exponent<double> > noexp_;

const auto parser = (x3::float_ | noexp_) >> "em";

int main() {
    std::string input = "-1.67em";
    auto first = input.begin();
    auto last = input.end();

    float value{};
    bool result = x3::phrase_parse(first, last, parser, x3::blank, value);

    if (result) {
        if (first == last)
            std::cout << "parse succesful: " << value << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "incomplete parse: " << value << '\n';
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "parse unsuccesful\n";
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
parse succesful: -1.67
```

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh. Yeah. That was well hidden. I'm happy to have not spent a lot of time. I could elaborate on the subtle points where my take is slightly better, but hey. Already at -1 so why bother.

Comment: Here's a +1 from me. Why is your take better :)?

Comment: Cheers. Two very subtle/mild points: the ordering with non-scientific first is slightly less generic (imagine if `"em"` was just "e" - it would mean that `3e7` woudn't be accepted or leave the `7` unparsed). So the ordering is slightly better. The other thing is prior knowledge: I've obvserved `real_parser<float, ...>` introduce unnecessary inaccuracies so using `real_parser<double, ...>` is my preferred method, even to parse into floats.